# prefuse visualization toolkit, trouble reading xml file

Tags: xml, parsing, prefuse

I am new to prefuse so I created a toy project but it seems I always have trouble with reading xml file:

public class testProfusion {

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    Graph graph = null;

    try {
        graph = new GraphMLReader().readGraph("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml");
    } catch ( DataIOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Error loading graph. Exiting...");
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

}

the address is valid and can be directly accessed. However no matter how I change, I always get error:

```
at prefuse.data.io.GraphMLReader.readGraph(Unknown Source)
at prefuse.data.io.AbstractGraphReader.readGraph(Unknown Source)
at testProfusion.main(testProfusion.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at prefuse.data.io.GraphMLReader$GraphMLHandler.endDocument(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me;-)!!!

Answer (score 0):

The http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml file is not a valid GraphML document.

Please try your code with http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/primer/simple.graphml

Read more about GraphML at http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/primer/graphml-primer.html